# React-Native TabBarIOS.Item

Tags: reactjs, react-native

TabBarIOS.Item icon in the IOS always gives me the below error

like THE TAB BAR ICON '{uri: contacts}' did not match with any known image or system Icon

The code is

```js
'use strict';

var React = require('react-native');
var {
  AppRegistry,
  TabBarIOS,
  NavigatorIOS,
  View,
  Text,
} = React;

var myPage = React.createClass({
  render: function () {
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hello</Text>
        <Text>World</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
})

var NewProject = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
       <TabBarIOS>
        <TabBarIOS.Item title="React Native" icon={{uri: 'contacts'}} selected={true}>
          <NavigatorIOS initialRoute={{ title: 'React Native', component: myPage }} />
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
        <TabBarIOS.Item title="React">
          <NavigatorIOS initialRoute={{ title: 'React Native', component: myPage }} />
        </TabBarIOS.Item>
      </TabBarIOS>
    );
  }
});

AppRegistry.registerComponent('NewProject', () => NewProject);
```

Comment: This might be the answer you are looking for: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/849#issuecomment-93179556

Answer (score 2):

I guess you want to use the system icons. You should use the systemIcon attribute for it.
The supported system icons are
'bookmarks', 'contacts', 'downloads', 'favorites', 'featured', 'history', 'more', 'most-recent', 'most-viewed', 'recents', 'search', 'top-rated'

in your case

```
    <TabBarIOS.Item title="React Native" systemIcon="contacts" selected={true}>
      <NavigatorIOS initialRoute={{ title: 'React Native', component: myPage }} />
    </TabBarIOS.Item>
```

The icon attribute is used to use imported images, as shown in this link
https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/849#issuecomment-93179556

Comment: If you use `systemIcon` you can not set the `title` so this example will not work as expected. See https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/tabbarios-item.html